# Problem identification: splitting string into tokens taken from a given, possible overlapping set

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

I am facing the following problem in a script I am trying to develop:

Given a string and a set of tokens, where the tokens are known and are overlapping (the set can contain the tokens 'a', 'b' and 'ab'), I need to split the string into a list of tokens from the set. I know there can be multiple ones, I don't need all of them, just a random one (obviously it is trivial to get an arbitrary one if I have all possible token lists).

The token set is known and guaranteed to have all possible characters of the input string, there is at a token which is equal to a single character for each possible input character.

Is it a known problem? If so, does it have known solutions? I am happy with adjacent literature I can use to jump-start my research.

Comment: Do you really mean 'random' or do you mean 'arbitrary'?  If 'random', what distribution on valid solutions do you require?  I'm wondering if you just want to know one tokenization and you don't care which one.  Also, what does 'guaranteed to have all possible characters of the input string' mean?  Does it mean that, for every character that occurs in the string, there is a token containing just that single token in the set of tokens?  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @D.W. added more details, but yes, your assumptions are correct.

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT:" or just append stuff at the end.  Instead, revise your question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  For instance, you can remove use of the word "random" and replace it with what you actually mean.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Answer (score 1):

This problem is often called the Word Break problem and is a classic exercise for dynamic programming.

Base case: if you don't have a string, it's a yes instance.

For every token, if the string ends with that token, remove that suffix from the string and recurse.

If no token is a suffix of your (non-empty) string, return false.

The running time is cubic (or more accurately the length of the string times number of tokens times length of the longest token). Perhaps.

---

A very simple recursive function with memoization in Python is given:

```python
@cache
def wordbreak(string, tokens):
    if not string:
        return True
    canbreak = False
    for token in tokens:
        if string.endswith(token):
            if wordbreak(string.removesuffix(token), tokens):
                return True
    return False
```

Beware that it's slower than necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start! i'll try and find a way to get an arbitrary tokenization without having to get all of them, as I was hoping it would be a bit less intensive.

Comment: You obviously don't have to iterate through all tokens. In fact, if construct a prefix trie of your reversed tokens, you can iterate backwards in the text looking only at actual hits. The above code snippet is for educational purposes only.